# Stacked UI elements: how to have only the visible ones to respond to click

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3 dropdown that are stacked on top of each other; I use canvas group to make the non relevant ones invisible; although the click is intercepted only on the topmost control.

How do you work around this? Should I keep track of the position in the hierarchy and swap it when I need to have a specific dropdown control so I can use it? Feels like a lot of work...hopefully is there an easier way?

Comment: You could set their `Raycast Target` property to false. (Thats part of the image component.)

Comment: @GunnarB. I think you should convert that into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` component of UI elements has a `Raycast Target` property that you can set to false. This will make them unclickable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; BTW just changing raycast target won't work...the mouse click is not properly intercepted, when turning the flag off and on; and this result in frustration when trying to click on a dropdown. Instead I did use a canvas group, and for some reason, changing the raycast target flag on the canvas group works much better. Thanks!